# Map array objects to another variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've Array of objects, I wanted to loop though the array and map the objects to a local variable

**Array Objects**

```
[
    {startDate: "05/01", endDate: "05/07", label: "05/01 - 05/07 (week1)"},
    {startDate: "05/08", endDate: "05/14", label: "05/08 - 05/14 (week2)"},
    {startDate: "05/15", endDate: "05/15", label: "05/15 - 05/15 (week3)"}
]
```

Now i wanted take only label object and push it to `this.dateLable`

**Expected**

```
    this.dateLable =[
{ id: '05/01 - 05/07', label: "05/01 - 05/07 (week1)" }, 
{ id: '05/08 - 05/14', label: "05/08 - 05/14 (week2)" },
{ id: '05/15 - 05/15', label: "05/15 - 05/15 (week3)"}
]
```

**My Code**

```
 this.weekByDates().find(x => x.label == push(this.dateLable) )
```

Please help me on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Show your code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `arr` is the initial array of objects:

```
this.dateLable = arr.map((x) => ({
  id: `${x.startDate} - ${x.endDate}`,  // es6 template literals
  label: x.label
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map` to transform the data in the array:

```js
let source = [{startDate: "05/01", endDate: "05/07", label: "05/01 - 05/07 (week1)"},{startDate: "05/08", endDate: "05/14", label: "05/08 - 05/14 (week2)"},{startDate: "05/15", endDate: "05/15", label: "05/15 - 05/15 (week3)"}];

let dateLable = source.map(v=> ({
    id: `${v.startDate} - ${v.endDate}`, label: v.label
}));
console.log(dateLable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

You can try following

```js
var arr = [
    {startDate: "05/01", endDate: "05/07", label: "05/01 - 05/07 (week1)"},
    {startDate: "05/08", endDate: "05/14", label: "05/08 - 05/14 (week2)"},
    {startDate: "05/15", endDate: "05/15", label: "05/15 - 05/15 (week3)"}
] 


this.dateLabel =arr.map(function(item){
   return {
       id : item.startDate + " - " + item.endDate,
       label: item.label
  };
});

console.log(this.dateLabel);
```